# Can't show file configuration Poller in Centreon

Tags: poller, centreon-api

I have a problem with centreon when i would like add a Poller. I don't have touch the gorgone file on the central server

Error MSG

[image: 1]

I reinstalled the poller and still the same problem, I think it comes from the server

the service gorgoned is running on the both machine

Answer (score 0):

You might also have your firewall or selinux still up and blocking traffic.

Did your poller install complete or is it stuck at the part where you have to copy the gorgone config to the CLI?

Do you already have the gorgone config file `/etc/centreon-gorgone/config.d/40-gorgoned.yaml` on your poller?